# Calculation not storing in DataFrame but works on print

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following calculation:
`np.maximum(0, np.prod([perf_asset, calc_arr['val']]) - amt_payout - np.prod([exposure, calc_arr['delta_1']]))`

Written out, this would be:

```
MAX(0, 0.8 × 105.015038 - 80 - TRUE × 5.3135)
MAX(0, 84.0120307692 - 80 - 5.3135)
= 0
```

If I print this, the output actually works but if I want to store it in a DataFrame, it doesn't:
`calc_arr['added_amt'] = np.maximum(0, np.prod([perf_asset, calc_arr['val']]) - amt_payout - np.prod([exposure, calc_arr['delta_1']]))`

The calculations stopped working all of a sudden. Before that I didn't even have to use `np.prod` and `np.sum`. I'm completely confused to be honest.

Complete loop:

```
j = 1
for i in [0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,-0.053,-0.0698,-0.1011,-0.1767,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271]:
    risky_return = i
    risk_free_return = (-0.0125/260)

    stock_val = stock_calc(j, stock_val['amt_payout'], stock_val['alloc_risky'], stock_val['alloc_risk_free'], stock_val['delta_1'], risky_return, risk_free_return)
    stock_vals = stock_vals.append(stock_val)
    j = j + 1
```

And the `calc_arr['val']` is retrieved:

```
calc_arr['val'] = np.sum([np.prod([(1 + perf_risky), alloc_risky]), np.prod([(1 + perf_risk_free), alloc_risk_free])])
```

Comment: It is interesting. If use `a = np.maximum(0, np.prod([perf_asset, calc_arr['val']]) - amt_payout - np.prod([exposure, calc_arr['delta_1']]))` and `cppi['added_amt'] = a` it doestn work too?

Comment: Or maybe need `cppi.ix[0, 'added_amt'] = a`, because `cppi['added_amt']` get scalar value to all column.

Comment: No, returns `NaN` in the array as well but prints correctly.

Comment: so value of `a` is `NaN`?

Comment: No, value of a is 0, as it should be.

Comment: So `cppi['added_amt'] = 0` doenst work also?

Comment: The funny thing is, the calculations all worked once upon a time. I will try the `.ix` route.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121229/discussion-between-spurious-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `append` values to `list` - `stock_vals` and then assign it to column:

```
stock_vals = []
for i in [0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,-0.053,-0.0698,-0.1011,-0.1767,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271]:
    risky_return = i
    risk_free_return = (-0.0125/260)

    stock_val = stock_calc(j, stock_val['amt_payout'], stock_val['alloc_risky'], stock_val['alloc_risk_free'], stock_val['delta_1'], risky_return, risk_free_return)
    stock_vals.append(stock_val)


calc_arr['val'] = stock_vals
```

I try it rewrite to list comprehension:

```
L = [0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,0.0627,-0.053,-0.0698,-0.1011,-0.1767,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271,-0.6271]

calc_arr['val'] = [stock_vals.append(stock_calc(j, stock_val['amt_payout'], stock_val['alloc_risky'], stock_val['alloc_risk_free'], stock_val['delta_1'], risky_return, (-0.0125/260))) for risky_return in L]
```